# Вызвать метод базового класса у всех полей в модели с помощью рефлексии

Tags: c#, рефлексия

У меня есть модель `DealModel` в которой есть кастомные свойства по типу `CustomInt`, `CustomDate`, `CustomDecimal` и.т.д

В базовом классе от которого наследуются кастомные свойства есть метод `bool IsModified()`

Нужно написать метод в котором будут вытянуты все свойства модели и вызван метод базового класса. Если, какое то свойство вернет `true` - то вернуть `true`, если все свойства вернули `false` - тогда вернуть `false`

```
public bool IsAnyFieldChanged(DealModel entity)
{
    bool isModified = false;
    // получаю список всех полей в моделе
    var fields = entity.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (var field in fields)
    {
        // а как быть тут?
    }

    return isModified;
}
```

Comment: Поля или свойства? Как оно (поле или свойство) должно узнать, что было изменено?

Comment: Исправил. Свойства в моделе. За то, было ли изменено свойство отвечает метод в базовом классе IsModified()

Comment: У Вас именно наследование или generic? Можно примеры CustomInt и базового класса?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не все поля, а поля, тип которых унаследован от определённого класса.
Так что

```
 var fields = entity.GetType().GetProperties();
```

меняем на

```
var props = bar.GetType()
   .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
   .Where(x=> x.PropertyType.BaseType == typeof(BaseFoo));
```

Тут мы получим все публичные свойства экземпляра, значения которых имеют тип, унаследованный от базового (типы указываю по примеру из фиддла).

Дальше всё просто - получаем значение, свойство приводим к базовому, проверяем на `IsModified`:

```
foreach (var prop in props)
{
    if (((BaseFoo)prop.GetValue(bar)).IsModified())
        changed = true;
}
```

Фиддл: https://ideone.com/tEEZ3W

Если всё так, как я думаю, и у вас не наследование, а generic-типы, то получение свойств меняем на:

```
 var props = bar.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                .Where(x => x.PropertyType.IsGenericType 
                           && x.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()==typeof(Foo<>) );
```

Тут мы получим все публичные свойства экземпляра, реализующиее определённый generic-класс.
А проверка на изменение, соответственно, будет выглядеть как:

```
foreach (var prop in props)
{
    if ((bool)(prop.PropertyType.GetMethod("IsModified")
                   .Invoke(prop.GetValue(bar), new object[] { })))
        changed = true;
}
```

Фиддл: https://ideone.com/Td2M4T

Comment: Только все-таки лучше проверять не BaseType, а IsSubclassOf